# Using CSS to make table's outer border color different from cells' border color

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I want to use CSS to set a color of the outer border of the table ...
Then the inner cells would have different border color ...

I created something like this :

```
table {
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border: 1px solid black; 
}

table td {
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Problem is, the table's color change and become red as you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/JaF5h/

If the border width of the table is increased to be 2px it will work : http://jsfiddle.net/rYCrp/

I've been dealing with CSS and cross browsers issues for so long ... This is the first time I face something like that and I am totally stuck ... No idea what to do!

Any one knows how to get that fixed with border-width:1px ?

Comment: I left out something important. jsFiddle "normalizes" the CSS with a reset sheet. If you unselect the "normalize css" checkbox on the left side you will get black border. There will be some extra padding to remove without the reset stylesheet though.

Comment: Every solution to this problem boils down to a hackish workaround because CSS does not give us a way to manually resolve collapsing border conflicts—it simply enforces an opinionated '[rule of thumb](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#border-conflict-resolution) … that at each edge the most "eye catching" border style is chosen'. I've yet to find one solution (and I think I've tried them all) that works well in all situations. Even `!important` fails in this space. Quite incredible that no one foresaw the desire to have a different coloured outer border on a table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would acheive this by using adjacent selectors, like so:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tr + tr {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}

td {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

td + td {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

It's a little bit repetitive, but it acheives the effect you're after by setting the top and left borders of the first row and column respectively, then overwriting the 'internal' rows and cells with red.

This won't of course work in IE6 as it doesn't understand the adjacent selectors.

http://jsfiddle.net/JaF5h/36/

Comment: Working perfectly ... Thanks. Didn't want to do it with adjacent selector frankly but it looks like there's no way else to do it.

Comment: Please note that the solution of John Catterfeld is not so perfect it seems to... See http://jsfiddle.net/JaF5h/37/ The inner borders overlay the main outer border With his example, we couldn't see it because it was 1 red pixel on a black line. With two white pixels it becomes obvious... unfortunately no solution yet

Comment: Unnecessarily 'repetitive' I would say, since the `tr` and `td` declaration blocks overwrite the collapsed table border with identical values, and are themselves overwritten by the adjacent sibling values for the cell borders. So you can happily delete those two lines. Also, a slightly more robust solution mght be to target the cells, not the rows, in all cases, so `tr + tr` becomes `tr + tr > td`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
tbody { display:block; margin: -1px; }
```

Comment: This one is working perfectly ... A minor issue showed is that the border of the cells close to the table is showing up too ... You can check what I mean here : http://jsfiddle.net/EpLj4/

Comment: ah, thought that was the desired effect. if you don't want that do this then:  tbody { display:block; margin: -1px }

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  I have made minor formatting changes in your answer to make use of the code highlighting in SO.

Comment: Good point, made the changes to the answer too. I've been reading stack overflow for quite some time, but never had an account. Still a bit of a newbie here :-)

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers didn't fully resolve this for me.  The accepted answer allows the internal borders to overlap the outer table border.  After some experimentation I came up with the following solution.

By setting the table collapse style to separate the internal borders do not overlap the outer.  From there the extra and doubled borders are eliminated.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Content</td>
     <td>Content</td>
     <td>Content</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Content</td>
     <td>Content</td>
     <td>Content</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

table tr td {
    border-right: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td{
    border-top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5ar81xg/

Comment: This is my usual approach. It should be noted though that this is not resistant against col- or rowspans. Both can cause border anomalies with this setup.

Answer (score 4):

Create a div surrounding your table.  Set the div border color for the outside of your table.  DO NOT border-collapse your table. Instead, let your cells separate to show the (inner borders) background color of the div beneath.  Then set the background cells to the background color of your choice.

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="tableDiv">
    <table id="studentInformationTable">
        <!-- Add your rows, headers, and cells here -->
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#tableDiv {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border: 2px solid brown;
    background-color: white;
}

table {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-color: brown;
}

td, th {
    background-color: #e7e1d3;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when table styles get complicated, this may just be the most reliable & least complicated method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following it worked for me:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid #000; 
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: this one works but the border width is set to 2px instead of 1px even when you remove the 1px