# How to make outer border of table to be of a colour different from inner in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, border, styling

What I want is this

[image]

What I am getting is this

[image]

My code is

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="10" bordercolor="blue">
```

I do not want to edit each td tag individually.
What's more no stylesheets are to be used in my project.

Comment: If you cannot include a style-sheet then use the `<style>` tag

Comment: Although that is also not allowed, could you please elaborate?

Comment: <style>
table {border: solid 2px blue;}
td {border:solid 1px gray;}
</style>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSS to make table's outer border color different from cells' border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875931/using-css-to-make-tables-outer-border-color-different-from-cells-border-color)

Comment: If this is some kind of HTML learning question and you aren't allowed to use inline styles or stylesheets, I suggest you find a different course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions here (from what I can see):

1. Wrap the table (with standard or silver border) in a div with a blue border.
2. Insert the table (with standard or silver border) in another table's cell. Give the "outer" table a blue border.

I think the first option is much better.

Comment: The first option requires a stylesheet. (And if stylesheets are allowed, no `div` trick is needed.)

Comment: No it doesn't, just use the `style=""` attribute of the `<div>`

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I agree with Mimisbrunnr: [div tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, the content of the `style` attribute is a stylesheet.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I'm fairly sure it's an attribute of the (X)HTML element and not a style sheet. It may define style rules for the element it is contained but, but it's not a style sheet

Comment: Well, in any case, the second option is always available if the OP's author feels the first option violates the no-css rule.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of defining style rules for a page. One is to do it in a separate file and to include that in via `<link ... />` the second method is to use a `<style>` tag, preferably in the `<head>` of the document.

```
<style type="text/css">
  table {
      border-color:#00F;
  }
  table td {
      border-color:#ccc;
  }
</style>
```

or something to that effect, should do what you want. Mind, I said that it is better to place the style in `<head>` but it can appear anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table cellpadding="2"><tr><td bgcolor="blue">
<table border="1" frame="void" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="white">
  <tr><td>foo<td>bar
  <tr><td>foo<td>bar
</table>
</table>
```

This is tricky, and the result matches your verbal description but not the image. The borders are solid, but I don’t think there is a way to set border color in HTML without making the border solid.

The trick is to place the real table inside a single-cell table, to remove the table around the real table (`frame="void"`) and to set a background color on the cell that contains the real table. The background color is set to the desired border color. The real table then needs a white background (or whatever your overall background is to be), since by default it would be transparent. The width of the fake border is controlled by the `cellpadding` of the outer table.

The code is valid HTML 4.01 Transitional (whereas the `bordercolor` attribute, though widely supported, is not valid).

Of course, things would be much easier using a stylesheet. Apart from a contest or a homework assignment with odd rules, the only situation I can imagine is an authoring environment where you cannot inject a `style` or `link` element and need to work inside `body`. But even there, you can actually use a `style` element—browsers allow it, even though specifications don’t.

Answer (score 1):

you can give border color in table for outer table border requirement and give the border in table td for internal td border.

see the fiddle for better understanding :- http://jsfiddle.net/nTFAF/4/

Comment: Your example conveniently has a thicker outer border on the table, which is why it takes priority over the inner `td` borders. Set the `table` border to `3px` and it'll vanish into thin air. Yes, it's an odd beast CSS.