# Table border should override cell border

Tags: html, css, border

the outer border of the table should be prior to the cell borders. How do I achieve this?
I want different colors but with a consistent outer border. The first example describes the problem:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red; border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid blue">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table style="border: 1px solid red" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid blue">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: border-collapse vs. cellspacing]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSS to make table's outer border color different from cells' border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875931/using-css-to-make-tables-outer-border-color-different-from-cells-border-color)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on Stackoverflow a few years ago. You can achive this easily but a bit hacky. If it's not working without, you have to add the `<tbody>` tag to your table too.

```
tbody { 
    display: block; 
    margin: -1px; 
}
```

Comment: The "display: block" crashes my layout.

Comment: The whole page layout or just your tables? What about applying ot to one single table?

Comment: Sorry. It actually affected and broke the table only.