# How to change properties of only the outer borders of bootstrap tables

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I want to change the `border` property like `border-color`, `border-style` and `border-radius` of only the outer border of the bootstrap 4 table, I tried but It's not working maybe properties are overriding. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSS to make table's outer border color different from cells' border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875931/using-css-to-make-tables-outer-border-color-different-from-cells-border-color)

Answer (score 0):

you can change default styles by editing bootstrap css file or using `<style>` in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: I am using cdn and I have tried to set the style but it was not working, When I tried to check that in developer mode it was got overridden by some other style I am not sure what was that

Comment: Why don't you try inline css?

Comment: I always try to keep my styles separate from my markup, that's why I usually don't use inline styling

Comment: You are right but you should choose between inline styles or CDN

Comment: Yeah, I think I have to dig into bootstrap library for this and figure out  how  I can achieve the desired result, thanks for your recommendation btw,